# What is the meaning of exit code 3 from Rez?

Tags: macos, exit-code

An XCode project on OSX 10.6 fails building due to exit code 3 when trying to run Rez.  What does this mean?  I'm sure the files exist and all paths are set correctly, and have valid content.  Google and AltaVista turn up nothing but others with the same question.

More generally, since I have a talent for creating errors on OSX, is there a list of all possible exit codes for Rez and what they mean?  Are these standard among all of Apples command line programs?

UPDATE:
Here's the first .r file that Rez tries to compile, but stops with exit code 3:

```
// The About box and resources are created in PIUtilities.r.
// You can easily override them, if you like.

#define plugInName          "HackFormat"
#define plugInCopyrightYear "1957"
#define plugInDescription \
    "Hackup of sample plugin SimpleFormat to test plugin making procedures (DSW)"




// Dictionary (aete) resources:

#define vendorName          "DarenTheMonkey"
#define plugInAETEComment   "simpleformat example file format module"

#define plugInSuiteID       'sdK4'
#define plugInClassID       'simP'
#define plugInEventID       typeNull // must be this


#include "PIDefines.h"
#include "Types.r"
#include "SysTypes.r"
#include "PIGeneral.r"
#include "PIUtilities.r"
#include "PITerminology.h"
#include "PIActions.h"
#include "HackFormatTerminology.h"  // Terminology for plug-in.

//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//  PiPL resource
//-------------------------------------------------------------------------------

resource 'PiPL' (ResourceID, plugInName " PiPL", purgeable)
{
    {
        Kind { ImageFormat },
        Name { plugInName },
        Version { (latestFormatVersion ",                            /* must be exactly this */
                keyInherits,                                /* must be keyInherits */
                classFormat,                                /* parent: Format, Import, Export */
                "parent class format",                      /* optional description */
                flagsSingleProperty,                        /* if properties, list below */

                "foo",
                keyMyFoo,
                typeBoolean,
                "foobar",
                flagsSingleProperty,

                "bar",
                keyMyBar,
                typeBoolean,
                "foobar",
                flagsSingleProperty
                /* no properties */
            },
            {}, /* elements (not supported) */
            /* class descriptions */
        },
        {}, /* comparison ops (not supported) */
        {}  /* any enumerations */
    }
};


resource StringResource (kHistoryEntry, "History", purgeable)
{
    plugInName ": ref num=^0."
};


// end file
```

and, from the xcode Build Results window, (just for this first .r file; rest are same)

```
Build HackFormat of project hackformat with configuration Debug

Check dependencies

[WARN]Warning: The Copy Bundle Resources build phase contains this target's Info.plist file 'Info.plist'.

Rez tmp/hackformat.build/Debug/HackFormat.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/HackFormat-A69F02213383561.rsrc HackFormat.r
cd /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat
/Developer/Tools/Rez -o /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/tmp/hackformat.build/Debug/HackFormat.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/HackFormat-A69F02213383561.rsrc -d SystemSevenOrLater=1 -useDF -script Roman -arch x86_64 -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/Debug -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/sampcomm -i sampcomm -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/sampcomm -i /home/dwilson/SW/SDK/AdobePS/adobe_photoshop_cs5_sdk_mac/photoshopapi/photoshop -i /home/dwilson/SW/SDK/AdobePS/adobe_photoshop_cs5_sdk_mac/photoshopapi/pica_sp -i /Developer/Headers/FlatCarbon -i /home/dwilson/SW/SDK/AdobePS/adobe_photoshop_cs5_sdk_mac/photoshopapi/resources -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/Debug -i /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/Debug/include -i sampcomm /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/../../../common/includes/MachOMacrezXcode.h -isysroot /Developer/SDKs/MacOSX10.5.sdk /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/HackFormat.r

### /Developer/Tools/Rez - SysError 0 during open of "/home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/../../../common/includes/MachOMacrezXcode.h".
Fatal Error!
### /Developer/Tools/Rez - Fatal Error, can't recover.
/home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/../../../common/includes/MachOMacrezXcode.h: ### /Developer/Tools/Rez - Since errors occurred, /home/dwilson/proj/PSPlug/hackformat/tmp/hackformat.build/Debug/HackFormat.build/ResourceManagerResources/Objects/HackFormat-A69F02213383561.rsrc's resource fork was not written.
Command /Developer/Tools/Rez failed with exit code 3
```

Comment: Are you using Rez?? Is it an old Carbon project?

Comment: Is Rez something old that shouldn't be used anymore?

Comment: Basically everybody (except old behemoths Adobe and Microsoft) stopped using `Rez`, which is a legacy mechanism to translate a textual resource file `.r` into the data in the resource fork in the old, pre-OS X Mac way.

Comment: I'm trying to create a plugin for Adobe Photoshop, in this case by copying one of the samples from their SDK and renaming files and making other changes.  It all compiles fine up until the .r stuff.  It's their xcode project file with a few changes e.g. fixing the paths to outside libraries.

Comment: Daren, could you post the URL where we can get the SDK?

Comment: http://www.adobe.com/devnet/photoshop.html

Comment: @Yuji let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/2249/discussion-between-darenw-and-yuji)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the problem!  In Project Setting, there was a bad path in Rez Prefix File.  It's supposed to be a path to a file MachOMacrezXcode.h.    Now it is obvious that this file wasn't being found when I look at the Build Results.    I have copied this file into my project source (since I want no dependencies on the original sample code I'm taking source from) and fixed the path.

Answer (score 2):

From the [Rez man page](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/Rez.1.html):

> Rez can return the following status codes:
>
> 0  no errors
>   1  error in parameters
>   2  syntax error in resource description file
>   3  I/O or program error

Comment: So just what is "I/O or program error"?  I found this with Google, but it doesn't seem helpful.

Comment: @DarenW It could mean that a file couldn't be found, the output file couldn't be created, or the permissions on some file caused an error. It could also mean there is an error in your input files. The result code really isn't all that helpful without an error message.

Comment: You need to show us your `.r` file which is causing the error.

Comment: I find it odd that xcode shows the commands and the exit code, but there aren't any real error messages.

Comment: @DarenW If you mouseover the command in the build log, a small icon will appear on the right. Click it to see the full command used and all output. If there isn't an error in there, then the command didn't give a message.

Answer (score 0):

man I'm just tagging along on this. I get `Command /Developer/usr/bin/Rez failed with exit code 3`

I've been looking everywhere for a comprehensive list of exit codes without any luck. Or at least any information on exit code 3.

Update: I just found this in here  http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Darwin/Reference/ManPages/man1/codesign.1.html (I'm not sure if this applies in any way to xcode as it seems to be part of the darwin documentation and I know very little about it):

codesign exits 0 if all operations succeed. This indicates that all codes were signed, or all codes
     verified properly as requested. If a signing or verification operation fails, the exit code is 1. Exit
     code 2 indicates invalid arguments or parameters.

```
Exit code 3 indicates that during verification, all
     path(s) were properly signed but at least one of them failed to satisfy the requirement specified with
     the -R option.

 For verification, all path arguments are always investigated before the program exits.  For all other
 operations, the program exits upon the first error encountered, and any further path arguments are
 ignored, unless the --continue option was specified, in which case codesign will defer the failure exit
 until after it has attempted to process all path arguments in turn.
```

Again I'm not sure but seems to be a permissions problem. Will investigate further!

Comment: I'm not sure how this applies. What are these "paths", what is "signed" and what is "verification"?  I haven't seen this jargon come up yet in Mac/Cocoa programming.